# What is the latest consensus on the so called C10K problem?

Tags: networking, asynchronous, network-programming, scalability

This is probably a well known discussion: http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

Although it's been updated in some places on the page, I'm wondering if there is a newer and more clearly articulated consensus or distilled wisdom on this challenge, with regards to the latest state of the operating systems and the available libraries?